# On the normalized block basic sequences in $c_{0}\widehat{\otimes}_{\pi} c_{0}$

Tags: banach-spaces

Let $c_{0}\widehat{\otimes}_{\pi} c_{0}$ be the projective tensor product of $c_{0}$ and $c_{0}$. Let $(e_{n})_{n}$ be the unit vector basis of $c_{0}$. For each $n$, define $z_{n}=e_{n}\otimes\sum_{j=1}^{n}e_{j}$. Then the basic sequence $(z_{n})_{n}$ is sub-symmetric. My question: Is each normalized block basic sequence of $(z_{n})_{n}$ equivalent to  $(z_{n})_{n}$? Thank you.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you trying to prove subprojectivity of this space?

Comment: No. I am trying to prove the space $\overline{span}\{z_{n}:n=1,2,...\}$ contains no uniformly copies of $l^{n}_{\infty}$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider $z_{2n+1} - z_{2n}$.

Comment: You are right,Bill. The purpose of my question is to prove that  the closed subspace  spanned by $(z_{n})_{n}$ has nontrivial cotype.